# What are the solutions to: $x(x-3)=x^2 -4$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

What are the solutions to: $x(x-3)=x^2 -4$ ?

Subtracting $x^2$ from both side results in the loss of the solution $(x=\infty)$.

My book says the solutions are $(x=\frac{4}{3},\infty)$

But is $(x=-\infty)$ another solution?

Is the answer $(x=\frac{4}{3},\pm\infty)$ or $(x=\frac{4}{3},\infty)$ ?

Comment: Let $x=1/h$

$$1-3h=1-4h^2$$

Comment: $\infty$ is not a number, so if you were to solve it in reals there's no such thing as a "loss of the solution $x=\infty$". It is not clear how your book defined $\infty$, perhaps they assume $\infty=-\infty$

Comment: There is a certain kind of convention where the absence of a sign before $\infty$ means $\pm \infty$.

Comment: @Frenzy Li  Great, so are you satisfied with x= ±∞ here ?

Comment: @Derek Hmm... I googled a bit, is the context the extended reals?  As $x\to-\infty$, the left and right hand side both approach $+\infty$ (the same with $x\to-\infty$, so I think writing both $x=\pm \infty$ is $x=\infty$ is ok.  With this convention I'm familiar with, $x\to+\infty$ has to be used to mean only approaching to the positive infinity.  Is this convention consistent with the usage in your book?

Comment: I can't seem to find any statement in the book regarding infinity. But none of the infinity signs in the book seem to have a +- sign.

Comment: @Derek -- What book are you using?

Comment: It is possible that $\infty$ is considered a solution of the equation $$\text{Left side}=\text{Right side}$$ iff $\frac{\text{Left side}}{\text{Right side}}$ approaches​ $1$ as $x$ grows indefinitely. That way, $\infty$ is a solution of $x^2=x^2+1$, but not of $x^2=x$ or $x^2=-x^2$. That is the most consistent way that I can come up with. For polynomials, then, the $\infty$ symbol needs not carry a sign, since going to $+\infty$ and $-\infty$ will agree on whether the above fraction tends to $1$. In the end, however, only the author of the book can tell us what he meant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The asymptotic behavior of any two [monic polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monic_polynomial) of the same degree is the same as $x\to+\infty$ and $x\to-\infty$, therefore approaching "infinity" to either side of the real line doesn't make a difference, so the author may simply write $\infty$ to mean $\pm\infty$.

Because your comment suggests that the author never writes $+\infty$ or $-\infty$, this reasoning works quite well.  If this is the reasoning, you could write $(\frac{4}{3},\pm\infty)$.

---

Another context is that the author makes extensive use of the [projectively extended real line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projectively_extended_real_line), where there is only *one infinity*, the $\infty$, as opposed to having both $+\infty$ and $-\infty$, in which case writing the solution as $\pm\infty$ is not acceptable.

---

Without knowing which is true, sticking to $\infty$ is safe.

Answer (score 3):

It makes little sense to say that this equation “has an infinite solution”, because it is a degree $1$ equation.

On the other hand there are different contexts where it can make sense.

Consider the *parametric* equation
\[
x(x-3)=kx^2-4
\]
If we set $y=x^2$, this becomes
\[
\begin{cases}
y=x^2 \\[4px]
y-3x=ky-4
\end{cases}
\]
which can be interpreted as the intersection of a parabola with a pencil of lines, in this case $x=\frac{(1-k)}{3}y+\frac{4}{3}$, centered at $(4/3,0)$. Each of these lines has two distinct intersections with the parabola, with the exception of the lines for

1. $k=25/16$ (tangent)
2. $k=1$ (vertical line)

In olden textbooks (at least in Italy), such problems were studied in painful details and the exceptional case 2 was often treated by saying that *one solution becomes infinite*.

This makes sense from a projective geometry point of view, but I find it just confusing. My feeling is that such “infinite solution” were introduced in order to avoid students consider the case $k=1$ as tangency (because the equation has a single solution).

By the way, this misses also another line, the one with “infinite $k$”.

Answer (score 3):

Whoa, whoa, whoa, back up.

$$x(x - 3) = x^2 - 4$$

Simplifying the left side:

$$x^2 - 3x = x^2 - 4$$

Now subtracting $x^2$ from both sides:

$$-3x = -4$$

And dividing both sides by $-3$:

$$x = \frac{-4}{-3} = \frac{4}{3}.$$

Graphing should lead to the same conclusion: four thirds is the only solution. As $x$ goes to either infinity, the gap between $x^2 - 4$ and $x^2 - 3x$ grows wider, though going to positive infinity, $x^2 - 4$ is greater, while going to negative infinity, $x^2 - 3x$ is greater.

In this view, infinity is something that can never be reached, that is always just beyond our reach. But if we can deal with infinities as if they were just a bunch of other algebraic quantities, does it make sense that $\infty^2 - 3 \infty = \infty^2 - 4$?

And what is $(-\infty)^2$? My guess is that $(-\infty)^2 = \infty$. Then $(-\infty)^2 + 3 \infty = (-\infty)^2 - 4$. I'm getting hung up on $(-\infty)^2 + 3 \infty$; if you can make sense of that as $(-\infty)^2 + 3 \infty = \infty$, then congratulations, you have shown that $x = -\infty$ is also a valid answer. But with Secretary of Educatuon Betsy DeVos wrecking our education system, good luck explaining it to anyone else.

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{align}
x(x-3)&=x^2 -4 \\ \\
\iff x^2-3x &= x^2 - 4\\ \\\iff 3x-4&=0\\ \\ \iff 3x&=4 \\ \\ \iff x &= \frac 43
\end{align}$$